# Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui

I want to prelaod all the customers and give it to the autocomplete whenever needed. I have this error caught up. The group search is global across the application.

```js
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var customers = $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:8081/customers/all",
             type: 'GET',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (data) {
                 $.map(data, function (v, i) {
                     return {
                         number: v.number,
                         name : v.name,
                     };
                 });
             }
         });

         $("#customer-search").autocomplete({
             minLength: 0,
             source: customers,
             select: function( event, ui ) {
                 $( "#group-search" ).val(ui.item.name);
                 $("#group-search-form").submit();
                 return false;
             },
         }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
             return $( "<li>" )
                 .append( "<div>" + item.name + " " + item.number + "</div>" )
                 .appendTo( ul );
         };





     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize **autocomplete** after ajax request complete, like below:

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var customers = [];
 $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:8081/customers/all",
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
           $.map(data, function (v, i) {
             return {
                 number: v.number,
                 name : v.name,
             };
         });

         $("#customer-search").autocomplete({
             minLength: 0,
             source: customers,
             select: function( event, ui ) {
                 $( "#group-search" ).val(ui.item.name);
                 $("#group-search-form").submit();
                 return false;
             },
         }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
             return $( "<li>" )
                 .append( "<div>" + item.name + " " + item.number + "</div>" )
                 .appendTo( ul );
         }; 
     }
 });



});
```

Comment: I want  customers to be a global variable  and save it once and use it whenever I needed. I still get the same error.

Comment: updated answer to use `customers` globally, just make sure you are initializing autocomplete after ajax success, otherwise customer is an empty array

Comment: Thanks, I have two problems now - autocomplete is just pulling up all the data filtering does not work. Second one autocomplete list is not rendered right away. Its displaying list after I clear the search tab.

Comment: I believe above question issue is fixed to pull data using autocomplete

for other 2 issues, **filtering:** where are you using filtering code to filter data? **not rendered right away:** it will work after ajax return some data so you need to wait before ajax request is getting complete

Comment: You can mark this answer as useful, so that it helps others too :)